# overiding get_form() method to customize admin view according to user

Tags: django, django-forms, python-2.7

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:   
        self.exclude=[]
    else:
        self.fields=['employer_verified']
    return super(EmployerAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

i have this code to override the get_form() method to customize the view according to the user 
it works just well when the super user login but the problem is when the staff member login and then the super user login only employer_verified is displayed i guess the problem is that 
nothing is excluded from fields which is equal now to 'employer verified'

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set `self.exclude` in the `get_form` method, it's not thread safe. Instead, you can define two different form classes, and return the correct one depending on `user.is_superuser`.

```
class EmployerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employer
        fields = ['employer_verified',]

class EmployerSuperUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employer

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:   
        return EmployerSuperUserForm
    else:
        return EmployerForm
        self.fields=['employer_verified']
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please click the tick above to show that I've answered your question.